# Spring data jpa fetch 200k records and expose endpoint to produce the fetch data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Spring data jpa fetch 200k huge records from table and expose endpoint to display fetch data in json response. I tried all possibilities like stream etc but it is impacting performance and while rendering response in postman, postman tool is getting crashed due to huge data set. any help or suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: You should try to optimize your code and see if you can send a lot of small data instead of a massive chunc. Also if you have a multicore CPU, you can use ParallelStreams to try to reduce the execution time (only for multicore CPUs or it will have the opposite result).

Comment: How to return small data since it is running in loop to fetch table data and adding into list and once loop completed 2Lac record return all list in one, any working example will be helpful

Comment: You can try to do a pagination system so that instead of looping into 1K record you just loop into the first 10 or 20, then the following 10/20, etc.

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* and *lac* that are not globally understood.